# Computing staggered/shifted means on Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given a Numpy array of shape 6 x 10, how would you compute the shifted means of the diagonals? A matrix like this

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Should result in an array of the following means

```
 [np.mean(0), np.mean(1, 0), np.mean(2, 1, 0), np.mean(3, 2, 1, 0), ..., np.mean(9, 8) + np.mean(9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** A much simpler method than the one I first posted:

```
>>> id_ = np.add.outer(*map(np.arange, A.shape))
>>> result = np.bincount(id_.ravel(), A.ravel()) / np.bincount(id_.ravel())
```

Update ends.

Here is a method using `as_strided`:

```
>>> A = np.repeat(np.arange(10)[None, :], 6, axis=0)
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> 
>>> sh_i, sh_j = A.shape
>>> st_i, st_j = A.strides
>>> 
>>> assert A.flags.c_contiguous
>>> assert sh_i <= sh_j
>>> 
>>> A_full = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A.ravel()[(sh_i-1) * sh_j:], (sh_j-sh_i+1, sh_i), (st_j, st_j-st_i))
>>> A_part = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A.ravel()[sh_i * sh_j - sh_i+1:], (sh_i-2, sh_i+1), (st_j, st_j-st_i))
>>> split = np.array((np.zeros((sh_i-2,), int), np.arange(sh_i-1, 1, -1), np.full((sh_i-2,), sh_i+1))).T
>>> full_means = A_full.mean(axis=1)
>>> part_means = A_part.cumsum(axis=1)[np.arange(sh_i-2)[:, None], split[:, 1:]-1].astype(float)
>>> part_means[:, 1] -= part_means[:, 0]
>>> part_means /= np.diff(split, axis=1)
>>> result = np.concatenate([A[0, 0, None], part_means[:, 1], full_means, part_means[:, 0], A[-1, -1, None]])
>>> 
>>> result
array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7. , 7.5, 8. ,
       8.5, 9. ])
```

The easiest way of understanding what's going on here is to inspect the strided views `A_full` and `A_part`. `A_full` contains the full-length diagonals, while `A_part` contains the bottom right reduced-length diagonals except the very corner concatenated with the top left reduced-length diagonals except the very corner.

```
>>> A_full
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> A_part
array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
       [7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

`split` contains the posititons where bottom-right ends and top-left begins.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> split
array([[0, 5, 7],
       [0, 4, 7],
       [0, 3, 7],
       [0, 2, 7]])
>>> pprint([np.split(Ap, sp) for Ap, sp in zip(A_part, split[:, 1, None])])
[[array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1])],
 [array([6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2])],
 [array([7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])],
 [array([8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]]
```

The rest of the code uses these bits to piece together the desired vector of means.

Comment: @BradSolomon No, you are right, there was an indexing error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Looks like it checks out now and is 2x fast as looping, to no surprise

Comment: @BradSolomon I've added another much simpler (2 lines) method if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being castigated for using a Python for-loop alongside NumPy code, you could take advantage of [`np.eye`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) to serve as a sliding mask along the diagonals without sacrificing a ton of runtime.

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> import numpy as np

>>> def diagonal_means(a):
...     m, n = a.shape
...     a_ = a[::-1].copy()
...     eyemask = partial(np.eye, *a.shape, dtype=np.bool_)
...     for k in range(1 - m, n):
...         yield a_[eyemask(k=k)].mean()
```

Example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(56).reshape(7, 8); a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
       [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
       [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])

# Means of: [0], [1, 8], [2, 9, 16], ...[55]
>>> np.array(list(diagonal_means(a)))
array([ 0. ,  4.5,  9. , 13.5, 18. , 22.5, 27. , 28. , 32.5, 37. , 41.5,
       46. , 50.5, 55. ])
```

Logically, you could reverse each mask generated with `eyemask`, but it's probably more efficient to reverse a copy of `a` first.